# How to make the view less complicated in regards to showing links only to certain users in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC view which needs a link to only be shown to certain user roles and only when it's in a particular state. I wrote it like this:

```
@if (!item.Validated && (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("regionaladmin") || HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("superadmin")) {
    <input type="button" class="btnvalidate" value="Validate" data-invoiceid=@item.InvoiceId /> <span>|</span>
}
```

So this is getting a little messy.

Is there a better solution to tidy this up a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Refactor the 'Business Logic' into a single method and call that instead:

```
@if (ShouldSeeInvalidateButton(item)) {
   // ...
}
```

And your function:

```
private bool ShouldSeeInvalidateButton(Item item)
{
    return !item.Validated && ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with testing more than 1 role at a time, an extension method could help you:

```
public static bool IsInRole(this IPrincipal user, params string[] roles)
{
    return roles.Any(role => user.IsInRole(role));
}
```

From the view, you can also access the User object directly (no need to go through the WebContext). You code becomes:

```
@if (!item.Validated && User.IsInRole("regionaladmin", "superadmin"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this approach too @Xavier

Comment: @JohnWeldon Your approach is better if the logic needs to be applied to more than 1 element in the page though.